# Android Game Leaking memory because of GLThread reference

Tags: android, opengl-es, memory-leaks, surfaceview

Right now I'm developing a game in Android (OpenGL ES 1.1) and I'm seeing that whenever I create a new SurfaceView (GLView) its thread is created. That's ok. The problem comes when I want to finish the Activity that holds the SurfaceView (and go back to the menu). It seems that the activities are not released because each GLThread is referencing it. This may finish with an OOM error.

Some MAT pictures:

[image: The MarkitActivity represents each single instance of the Activity that deals with SurfaceView]

[image: The list of all the activities in memory]

[image: What is holding the Activities from GC]

The first picture: the MarkitActivity represents each single instance of the Activity that deals with SurfaceView.

The second picture: The list of all the activities in memory.

The Third Picture: What is holding the Activities from GC.

If any code is needed I will post it. Nevertheless I have already tried the following things:

->Weak reference of the Activity Context to the renderer and to the surfaceview.

->Application Context instead of Activity Context (in normal and weak mode).

->Trying to stop (in a hard way) the thread (interrupt) and waiting for join (Which the program does it, but the thread does not care, it is still there...)

->Trying without debugging, just in case in debugger mode the values changes (the MAT pictures are without debugger).

->Trying the Activity as singleInstance mode. Weird results and errors everywhere.

->onPause and onResume are correctly controlled for the view.

Any hint, idea, question or help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Carlos.

Comment: HI ! Did you find a way around this ? Because I am currently experiencing exactly the same problem (only on older versions of Android - Android 4.2.2 has a different behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with threads (but not using OpenGL), and end up solving it using a simple trick.

Before exting activity (in `onPause()` or `onStop()`, try nulling the thread like this:

```
myThread = null;
```

It seems that it makes the `Thread` GC collectable, and therefore you activity becomes also collectable.

It worked for me, as well as for some people with similar problems to whom I gave the same suggestion.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Luis, Thanks for your fast answer. The main issue here is that I do not have the possibility to access the Thread itself (or at least to the loop and the main variable that keeps it alive, it is in the Android core).

Comment: I'm not experienced with OpenGL, but you can try nulling the GL top level element that holds the reference to the thread (maybe your GLSurfaceView or ClearRenderer objects).

Comment: Already tried, the thread is alive so it still has the references. :(