# Killing zombie GLThreads in android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

I experience an OpenGL issue with my game app for android. The main `game` activity features OpenGL ES powered graphics. Whenever a player loses the game, clicks the `back` button, etc. he is returned to a map choice UI, which does not feature any OpenGL elements.

The bug appears a bit indeterministic but calling these methods that stop the `game` activity multiple times and then restarting the `game` again causes multiple GLThreads to pop up and never get destroyed. These remain as zombie threads and harm performance.
After multiple `play`->`back` cycles the AndroidDeviceMonitor shows `main` thread, a `thread` (which is a thread I spawn and control), and around 20 `GLThread`s of which only one does meaningful job, but others also call things like Object.wait() etc.

I have no access to the OpenGL threads, they are being spawned by [GLRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html); also I see no place that could possibly have a reference to these, as I only hold a single renderer at any given time.
I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367800/android-game-leaking-memory-because-of-glthread-reference), but the only answer wasn't helpful.

How do I kill those/stop them from being leaked after returning from the OpenGL activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more painful investigation I found out that the garbage collector normally does indeed dispose of those threads. However if you are doing more complex things its easy to leave some references behind. In my case the GLSurfaceView was not the only surface view, I was inserting it into a relative layout like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_game);
layout.addView(gameEngine.getSurfaceView(), 0);
```

This apparently causes references to remain even after the activity finishes. The fix was to manually 'unpin' the GLSurfaceView from the hierarchy when destroying the activity

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_game);
    if (layout != null) {
        layout.removeView(gameEngine.getSurfaceView());
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: After even more testing I found out that while this solution is in the right direction, the layout must also be unpinned in `onStop` method - this is what is being called when the activity is left normally. `onDestroy` only happens if the device stops the activity due to, for example, lack of memory.
Finally, there is no way to tell `onStop` due to leaving the activity for good from `onStop` due to just pressing the power button, or opening Facebook messanger on top of the activity. For this reason in `onRestart` you need to insert the `GLSurfaceView` back into the structure, so that the app works correctly after being suspended by other actions.